# Get consecutive days of rows in table

Tags: sql

So I am trying to create a table that stores information about tables failing quality tests.
My goal is to create a table with the current tables who've been failing some sort of test for more than 2 days IN A ROW. Though I am unable to tackle all possibilities of entries from the logs table I am manipulating.

Here's the query I am using:

```
SELECT run_time,
full_table_name,
    expectation_type,
    meta,
    expectation_columns,
    origin_type,
    MAX(consecutive_days) as consecutive_days
FROM
(WITH a AS (
    SELECT
        full_table_name,
        expectation_type,
        date_trunc('day', run_time) AS run_time,
        origin_type,
        meta,
        expectation_columns
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE is_successful = false
        AND origin_type = 'DWH_TESTS'
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
)
SELECT
    full_table_name,
    expectation_type,
    meta,
    expectation_columns,
    origin_type,
    run_time,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY full_table_name, expectation_type order by run_time) AS consecutive_days
FROM a )
GROUP BY full_table_name,
    expectation_type,
    meta,
    expectation_columns,
    origin_type,
    run_time
having MAX(consecutive_days) > 2
ORDER BY run_time desc
```

Thing is, it accumulates all rows with false results. I need the accumulation of the consecutive.
Meaning:
If I had one table that been failing the same expectation day after day, I'd want to save it as a row, with the start date of this failing session, according to today. Though, once it been settled, I don't want it to still appear in query results (Unless it again surpassed two days threshold.)
Been trying to solve this for few days now, unsuccessfully.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not tag a question with lots of product tags, just include the product tags that are relevant from this question's point of view!

Comment: Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example